# constructing a dataframe from joined SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

from the query:

```
 session.query(Record, RecordMeasurement).filter(Record.record_pkid==RecordMeasurement.record_fkid)
```

i would like to construct 1 dataframe consisting of the values from Record columns:

```
['datetime', 'record_number']
```

and RecordMeasurement columns:

```
['power', 'voltage', 'temperature']
```

the dataframes column order does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your query to have only the columns you need:

```
query = (session.query(
    Record.datetime, Record.record_number, 
    RecordMeasurement.power, RecordMeasurement.voltage, RecordMeasurement.temperature,
    )
    .filter(Record.record_pkid==RecordMeasurement.record_fkid)
)
```

and then call:

```
import pandas as pd
# ...
df = pd.read_sql(query.statement, query.session.bind)
```